# How can I show line numbers by default with the 'git grep' command?

Tags: git

I know I can use the `-n` flag in `git grep` to show the line numbers of the results, i.e

```
git grep -n "some string"
```

but how could I include this flag by default without making an alias? I found `git config --global grep.lineNumber true` but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Your global config command adds `lineNumber = true` under `[grep]` to `~/.gitconfig` for me, but I also don't see any difference when using `git grep`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I set my `grep.lineNumber` using your command and it worked for me.

Consider using [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com). It's significantly more programmer-friendly and comes in the repositories of most major Linux distributions.

Comment: git grep is much faster if there are many untracked or ignored files.

Answer (score 60):

From the git grep manual:

```
Options:

   -n, --line-number
       Prefix the line number to matching lines.
```

---

```
Configuration:

   grep.lineNumber
       If set to true, enable -n option by default.
```

To turn on globally: `git config --global grep.lineNumber true`

Comment: Oh I should also note that `git grep` is faithful to the arguments of plain `grep`.

Answer (score 28):

Under .gitconfig file

add this section

```
[grep]                                                                                                                           
  linenumber = true
```

line number would be showed if you using git grep

Comment: Okay, that makes sense and it works.
But I do lose the colours in the output after using 'grep "text" *.py' for example. How do I avoid this?Thanks, Roland

Answer (score 13):

The command you use

```
git config --global grep.lineNumber true
```

is the correct way to enable -n option by default.

But this feature is not available until v1.7.5-rc1. Check your local document for more information.

```
git grep --help
```

Also if you are interested, here is the commit introduced this feature:

[grep: allow -E and -n to be turned on by default via configuration](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b22520a37c8472751f2c4b3da9b5bc4e5aa5a0a3)